# Redirect a subdirectory to a URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Im trying to redirect a subdirectory to a external URL hiding the URL. I already use htaccess to redirect the domain to a subdirectory and I want to keep this redirection showing the 'blog' subdirectory URL.

My code is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/?$ http://othersite.com/subdirectory [L,R=301,NC]
```

What I need to change to hide the URL only of the second redirection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't "mask" the URL if you're redirecting requests to an external website. If I understand your intentions, you need to proxy the requests. Take a look at the Apache [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) module. This will allow you to send requests from your server to a different server while masking the URL - it happens behind the scenes. Just be mindful of the warnings in the mod_proxy documentation as this has the potential to be abused (your server becomes the intermediary), depending on what you're doing with it.